# Message: Non-static method Updater_helper::arrayExtend() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-updater

Getting an error with **Dev Demon updater**:

> Message: Non-static method **Updater_helper::arrayExtend()** should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

REF #TT

Answer (score 2):

This is known error of Upgraded PHP version.

As you know a static method should ideally defined as `static function(){}` where **static** means the method can be called without an instance of the class.

For current scenario, Follow the staps:

1. Open FTP and go to `system > expressionengine > third_party > updater > libraries` folder.
2. Open file named **updater_helper.php**
3. Search function `function arrayExtend(` and change it from

   ```
   public function arrayExtend($a, $b) {
   ```

   TO

   ```
   public static function arrayExtend($a, $b) {
   ```

**arrayExtend** is not a single function  that is static and defined normally. There is more functions in same file

> getThirdPartyPath()
>
> getThemePath()
>
> getThirdPartyThemePath()
>
> arrayExtend($a, $b)

You need to change all this functions to **static** by adding **public static function fun_name()**